# Fading effect between switching divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/ for my main pages, the code below is used within a single page to showcase other different content info. All pages coded are in one index file.

The code below is used to switch between divs.
I tried using simple javascript onclick to make the pages fadeIn/fadeOut but it couldn't work.

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(idInfo) {
    var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
        sel[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('container' + idInfo).style.display = 'block';
}
$("#fade").click(function () {
    $('#container1').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#container2').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#container1, #container2, #container3 {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="fade" onclick="return showDiv('1')"><img src="img/thumbnail1.png" /><br>click to see content 1</a>
<a href="#" id="fade2" onclick="return showDiv('2')"><img src="img/thumbnail2.png" /><br>click to see content 2</a>
<a href="#" id="fade3" onclick="return showDiv('3')"><img src="img/thumbnail3.png" /><br>click to see content 3</a>

<div id="container1">content1</div>
<div id="container2">content2</div>
<div id="container3">content3</div>
```

Just need the .onclick fade effect to work after clicking on the link.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are aiming for:

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gG332/)

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="1">click to see content 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="2">click to see content 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="3">click to see content 3</a>
</div>

<div class="content-divs">
 <div>content0</div>
 <div>content1</div>
 <div>content2</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".links a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('toggle');
    showDiv(id);
});  

function showDiv(id) {
    // hide all other
    var divs = $('.content-divs');
    divs.children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();   
    });
    // fade the correct one in.
    divs.children('div:nth-child('+id+')').fadeIn();                      
}
```

Same css.
Since you are already using jQuery, why not use all it's functions?

You could do that with onclick="showDiv(id)", but jsfiddle does not work with that, so .data('toggle') is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be making this a little bit more complicated then it needs to be, try this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var curr = 1

      $('.fader').click(function(){
         var next_attr = $(this).data('num');

         if(curr != next_attr){
            $('div[data-num="'+curr+'"]').hide(1000, function(){ 
               $('div[data-num="'+next_attr+'"]').show(1000); 
            });

            curr = next_attr
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="links">
   <a class=".fader" data-num="1">Show Container 1</a>
   <a class=".fader" data-num="2">Show Container 2</a>
   <a class=".fader" data-num="3">Show Container 3</a>
</div>

<div class="containers">
   <div id="container1" data-num="1">Container 1</div>
   <div id="container2" data-num="2">Container 2</div>
   <div id="container3" data-num="3">Container 3</div>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
#container2, #container3{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

that should give you the ability to switch between the 3 containers by clicking the links corresponding to them. I used a data attribute to link the containers to there links.  When a link is clicked it looks for div with the same data-num and fades out the current one once its faded out it fades in the new one and sets the curr variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in pure CSS. (Not supported for IE 8-)

http://jsbin.com/eVeNeSO/1/edit

**CSS**:

```
body {
   background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
   background-color: #001;
}

/* Header Styling and Positioning */
#container ul {
   list-style:none;
   margin: 2em 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.5em;
}

   #container li {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0 1em;
   }

   #container li a {
      margin: 0 1em;
      color: #09b;
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #333;
      padding: .6em;
      border-radius: 25em;
   }

   #container li a:hover {
      color: #099;
      background: #444;
   }

   #container li a:active {
      color: #066;
      background: #222;
   }

/* Content Area */
.content div {
   width: 50%;
   margin: 2em auto;
   padding: 1em;
   background: #333;
   border: 1em solid #555;
   color: #fff;
}

/* hide unselected targets */
.content div:not(:target) {
   display: none;
}
/* display selected target */
:target {
   display: inherit;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<article id="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla at feugiat odio. Proin sit amet eros ac diam tempus tempor. Fusce gravida ut nisi in consectetur. Sed hendrerit sapien id metus adipiscing, id vehicula lacus fermentum. Proin mollis facilisis erat, eu sollicitudin diam scelerisque ut. Phasellus non mollis nisl. Vestibulum ac mi quis metus mollis fermentum. Donec pharetra consequat lacinia. Vestibulum porta tortor purus, non fermentum turpis congue eget. Nulla varius augue dolor, at pellentesque diam volutpat in. Vestibulum vitae ligula eu eros tristique accumsan. Mauris sagittis iaculis lorem id egestas. Suspendisse potenti. Cras faucibus dolor turpis, ac ultrices dolor rhoncus a.

        <p>Etiam aliquam magna vitae hendrerit accumsan. Nam venenatis risus a tempor semper. Nullam ac est nec dolor pellentesque laoreet ac ac nisi. Ut sit amet magna nunc. Vestibulum orci ipsum, pretium nec venenatis vel, lacinia et magna. Proin dignissim dui ligula, eget pretium nisl ultrices eu. Etiam sit amet nunc non nisl scelerisque dignissim a sed sapien.</p>

        <p>Quisque auctor sit amet mi sed porta. Fusce nec erat eros. Suspendisse et diam sit amet quam pretium sollicitudin quis nec enim. Nam fermentum risus dui, non volutpat dolor pellentesque nec. Quisque interdum, neque eu feugiat hendrerit, risus augue malesuada mauris, non vestibulum ante erat quis purus. Nunc scelerisque sapien vel leo bibendum, vel dapibus ipsum ultricies. Cras commodo lacus quis nunc eleifend iaculis. Nam adipiscing ipsum non justo ultrices, sit amet vestibulum urna vehicula. Praesent porttitor neque et dictum euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam adipiscing, neque ut dictum ultricies, dui odio aliquet dui, ac rhoncus neque nulla a enim.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut purus leo, varius pellentesque vestibulum at, lobortis quis est. Suspendisse mattis leo vel eros faucibus adipiscing. Phasellus sed nisl eu lectus blandit dignissim vel id nibh. Donec rutrum felis urna, sed elementum urna venenatis quis. Praesent vel tortor sed felis sodales lobortis eget eget nulla. Aliquam bibendum elit eu nunc facilisis, varius tempor lectus mattis. Aenean sed aliquet orci. Aliquam viverra molestie ultrices.

        <p>Nullam luctus imperdiet risus, vel convallis massa interdum id. In ultricies pulvinar libero vitae sodales. Fusce eleifend varius tincidunt. Nulla sed blandit nibh. Ut sollicitudin, metus et sagittis tincidunt, nisl felis ultricies ante, eu dapibus massa odio sed nunc. Pellentesque semper eros dui, ac mollis nunc dictum non. Quisque ultrices sapien at velit pellentesque, at lacinia est commodo. Morbi commodo in neque eu tempor. Curabitur eu mattis diam, eu tristique mauris.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse sit amet lacus rutrum, faucibus augue vitae, euismod nibh. Mauris aliquet nisi in nibh aliquam, et ullamcorper turpis mattis. Vestibulum ut hendrerit libero, eu ultricies odio. Etiam sodales vehicula dignissim. Vestibulum libero tellus, luctus sed imperdiet quis, malesuada sed nunc. In aliquet pellentesque erat pellentesque fringilla. Aenean egestas ipsum eu nunc auctor, nec vestibulum est varius. Integer convallis, orci sit amet sagittis hendrerit, purus ligula dictum dolor, in lobortis ligula lacus pulvinar lorem. Sed pulvinar porttitor egestas. Duis ac ante ipsum. Donec sem odio, sollicitudin in fermentum egestas, gravida sed diam. Nam condimentum augue ut ligula dapibus sodales. Donec blandit sem non cursus aliquam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="services">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus posuere porta suscipit. In ac purus quis lectus blandit rutrum eu vitae nisi. Nunc vel ante at enim imperdiet ultrices et non erat. Vestibulum sagittis facilisis nulla. Ut quis turpis sit amet enim volutpat tincidunt. Vivamus vel ornare neque. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis tincidunt mi et ipsum cursus, vitae tincidunt ipsum fringilla. Integer eu mollis elit, in tincidunt neque.

        <p>Maecenas ac est gravida, iaculis mauris vitae, tempus enim. Mauris ut nisi dapibus, commodo massa sed, iaculis augue. Cras sit amet leo libero. Mauris ac dui lorem. Aenean velit risus, ornare molestie neque ac, feugiat cursus tellus. Duis commodo lacinia felis, vitae aliquam mauris consectetur cursus. Donec arcu orci, sollicitudin eu lacus id, ultricies sollicitudin ligula. Vivamus ac egestas ipsum. Duis aliquam suscipit tristique. Vestibulum aliquet bibendum arcu, in adipiscing arcu sagittis ut. Aenean in leo risus. Morbi vitae nibh in eros accumsan consequat in ac lacus. Maecenas pretium mattis justo non euismod. Sed vel velit sollicitudin, posuere mi nec, dictum lectus.</p>

        <p>Nullam nisl nisi, dignissim ultrices cursus id, aliquet vel purus. Praesent velit purus, pharetra id eros id, viverra ultricies velit. Phasellus sed lacinia neque, at dictum odio. Mauris eget accumsan augue, ac imperdiet magna. Proin commodo sem id purus vulputate mollis. Nunc a dignissim urna. Nam facilisis, lectus sit amet blandit egestas, velit tortor imperdiet massa, eu elementum lorem dolor nec diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus sit amet nisl turpis. Nulla vel nulla ut odio feugiat ultrices. Ut id consequat sem.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```